# How can I define a sequence of Integers which only contains the first k integers, then doesnt contain the next j integers, and so on

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence, integer-sequence

I need a list of integers to check if a variable has one of the values of the list.
`If[ MemberQ[List,x], Green, Red]`
The list contains integers and is characterized by two parameters, lets call them k and j, which should be variable.

If `k=1` and `j=1` then the list would look like this: `{1,3,5,7,9,11,....until listmax}`

If `k=2` and `j=3` then the List would look like this: `{1,2,6,7,11,12,16,17,.....until listmax}`

Whereas `listmax` should be kept variable.

Generally speaking, the List contains the first k integers, then doesnt contain the next j integers, then contains the next k integers, then doesnt contain the next j integers and so on and so on.

In the end I need the List to decide whether `x` has one of the values of the List, so if there is a way to skip the part where one has to define the list and can directly check if x has one of those values, that would also do the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
BlockMap[Splice, Range@listmax, k, k + j]
```

Since you haven't defined the edge case behavior, this might not actually give you what you want. For example:

```
k = 2;
j = 3;
listmax = 5;
BlockMap[Splice, Range@listmax, k, k + j]
(* {1, 2} *)

listmax = 6;
BlockMap[Splice, Range@listmax, k, k + j]
(* {1, 2} *)
(* you might have wanted {1, 2, 6 *)

listmax = 7;
BlockMap[Splice, Range@listmax, k, k + j]
(* {1, 2, 6, 7} *)
```

**Update**

If you want different behavior at the upper end of the range, then something like this might be better:

```
Flatten[Partition[Range@listmax, k, k + j, {1, 1}, Nothing]]
```

(Unlike @Alan's solution, this one will take elements at the end even if there isn't a full k+j "block".)

Answer (score 11):

```
Flatten@Partition[Range[listmax], k + j][[All, ;; k]]
```

**Edit:** Or, using the 3rd argument to `Partition`,

```
Flatten@Partition[Range@listmax, UpTo@k, k + j]
```

Answer (score 6):

> In the end I need the List to decide whether `x` has one of the values of the List, so if there is a way to skip the part where one has to define the list and can directly check if x has one of those values, that would also do the job.

To skip creating the list, you can check if $1 \le x \le \text{listmax}$ and $1 \le \text{Mod}[x, k+j] \le k$.

You can check the correctness using `Solve`:

```mathematica
k = 2;
j = 3;
listmax = 30;
Solve[1 <= x <= listmax && 1 <= Mod[x, k+j] <= k, x, Integers]
```

```
{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 6}, {x -> 7}, {x -> 11}, {x -> 12},
 {x -> 16}, {x -> 17}, {x -> 21}, {x -> 22}, {x -> 26}, {x -> 27}}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, why bother creating the list if we can check directly

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f]

f[k_,j_,listmax_]:=Flatten@NestWhileList[#+k+j&,Range[k],Last@#<listmax-Max[k,j]&]
```

```
f[1,1,20]

(* {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19} *)
```

```
f[2,3,20]

(* {1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17} *)
```

```
f[5,3,20]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[k, j, listmax, sieve];
sieve[k_Integer, j_Integer, listmax_Integer] := 
 If[Mod[#, k + j, 1] > k, False, True] & /@ Range[listmax]
```

Usage:

```
sieve[3, 1, 22]
```

> {True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, 
> False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True}

which can be used with in conjunction with `Pick`:

```
listmax = 20;
Pick[Range@listmax, sieve[1, 1, listmax]]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}

```
listmax = 23; 
Pick[Range@listmax, sieve[5, 3, listmax]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}

```
listmax = 19
Pick[Range@listmax, sieve[2, 3, listmax]]
```

> {1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17}

Answer (score 2):

Per your update:

> directly check if x has one of those values

You could do this:

```
TheCheck[k_, j_][n_] := Mod[n, k + j, 1] <= k
```

We can test it with your example:

```
TheCheck[2, 3] /@ Range[17]
(* {True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True} *)

Select[Range[17], TheCheck[2, 3]]
(* {1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17} *)
```